# Inherrit Page_Load from base class. Correct Object Oriented programming

Tags: asp.net, inheritance

I have functionality I reuse in every web form. So I want this reuse in a base class and have the web form inherit the base class.  Does my example use correct Object oriented practice ??
 Here is an example:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
namespace Template1
{

  public abstract class AllPageBaseClass : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    public AllPageBaseClass()
    {
      this.Load += new EventHandler(this.Page_Load);
    }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
              if (Session["stuff"] == null)
                  Response.Write("Session Is Empty");
              // More error checking common to all pages here
         }
     }
 }


using System.Lots_Of_Stuff;
```

// Do I need System; and System.Web; here ??

```
namespace Template1
{
    public partial class Home : AllPageBaseClass
    {
        protected new void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        // All unique Page_load stuff here
        }
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to subscribe to the Load event.

Example of one of my projects:

```
public class SecuredPage:System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        if (...) 
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Your contentpage should look like this:

```
 public partial class Home : AllPageBaseClass
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          // All unique Page_load stuff here
        }
        ....
    }
```

You may also have a look at what the [new operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is for.

Comment: I got it (and the new operator part). Works good! Thanks! But why use OnInit?

Comment: I'm glad that I could be of help. Please accept my answer and upvote it ;) Some stuff needs to be done in the OnInit rather in the OnLoad event because of the ASP.Net Lifecycle. In the project I copied this from, I had to write some code in the OnInit. If you want to read more on this matter, check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I understand the Lifecycle well enough. I think the OnInit is needed because I didn't subscribe to the Load event. I wanted the base class to run before the Load event anyway - so it makes sense.  BTW, the base class only seems to need "using System;"